# jQuery preventDefault issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have an interesting case: I'm using [this plugin](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/) for a tag input field. When I click enter to add tags to the tags field, the form submits. So I put the code below to prevent the form from submitting:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).keydown(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

And now when I press enter in the tag input does not create a new tag in the field. The default enter behavior is used in the tags plugin.

Is there a way around it which doesn't involve changing the plugin?

Comment: Try removing `return false;` as it also stops event propagation. `preventDefault()` alone is enough to stop the form submitting

Comment: Thanks for commenting. It didn't work. It prevents the form submit and the tag plugin enter as well

Comment: Get rid of `return false` as Mr. McCrossan suggested, then place `event.preventDefault()`  right above `if(event.keyCode == 13) {...`

Comment: Do you have `13` as a value for  `confirmKeys` option e.g.  `confirmKeys: [13, 44]`

Comment: Please show the code where you use the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can check where the keydown event is happening with event.target.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).keydown(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 13 && !$(e.target).is("input[name=fieldName]")) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, here it never comes to the point of the `window` event listener before processing the `form` event listeners, eg.: submit.
Events always bubble up the dom. So the `form` always comes before `window`. Therefore it doesn't help to preventDefault because the default is already happened for the `form` when it comes to the `window` event.
Add the keydown listener to the `form` itself and it should work.

Edit: Or even better because more exact - Add keydown listener only to the fields you want to preventDefault.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#form-content').on('submit',function(event, can_submit){
        if(!can_submit){
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    })
});

function formSubmit() {
    $('#form-content').trigger('submit', [true])
}
```

Then I use a link as the save button:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btnSubmit" onclick="formSubmit()" >{% trans "Save" %}</a>
```

Thanks for the answers!